# Find the lowest value in a given list?

Tags: java

So I have a list, and I'm supposed to return the average, the highest value, and the lowest value.
I have the highest value and the average nailed down. I can't figure out how to prompt the program to return the lowest value.
Here's my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class PopData
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
  int sum = 0;
  int average = 0;
  int total = 42;
  int high = 0;
  int low = 0;

  File file = new File("USPopulation.txt");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

  while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
      int number = inputFile.nextInt();

      sum = sum + number;
      average = sum / total;

      if (number >= high) {
       high = number;
   }
 }
 inputFile.close();
 System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + average);
 System.out.println(high);
 System.out.println(low);
  } 
}
```

Comment: A **really** explanatory answer is to just flip the logic comparison in `number >= high`. Which makes me think you didn't implement that part yourself?

Comment: @AriK actually not true. Simply changing the if statement isnt enough. The inital value for low cant be 0 for it to work, would have to be either the max value of an int or a different approach would need to be used.

Comment: @fusion_ow it should be `number > high` not `>=` .. more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same technique you used for lower...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class PopData
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
  int sum = 0;
  int average = 0;
  int total = 42;
  int high = 0;
  Integer low = null;

  File file = new File("USPopulation.txt");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

  while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
      int number = inputFile.nextInt();

      sum = sum + number;
      average = sum / total;

      if (number >= high) {
       high = number;
      }
      if( low == null || number < low)
        low = number;
 }
 inputFile.close();
 System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + average);
 System.out.println(high);
 System.out.println(low);
  } 
}
```

You could also use an `int` rather than an Integer in which case you'd set int to Integer.MAX_VALUE

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class PopData
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
  int sum = 0;
  int average = 0;
  int total = 42;
  int high = 0;
  int low = Integer.MAX_VALuE;

  File file = new File("USPopulation.txt");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

  while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
      int number = inputFile.nextInt();

      sum = sum + number;
      average = sum / total;

      if (number >= high) {
       high = number;
      }
      if(number < low)
        low = number;
 }
 inputFile.close();
 System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + average);
 System.out.println(high);
 System.out.println(low);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Comment: @fusion_ow Your welcome. If you feel this answered your question dont forget to accept it as the answer by hitting the check mark near the voting controls.